# Why isn't the table command working?

Tags: support, bug

In this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572029/a-problem-on-tossing-coins-and-the-root-of-quadratics)

I'm trying to render some tables using this code
probability distribution of $C_1$
| event | probability
| :------- | :----------------: |
| 0 heads   | $\frac{1}{9}$             |
| 1 Head | $\frac{4}{9}$           |
| 2 heads |$\frac {4}{9}$

probability distribution of $C_2$
| event | probability
| :------- | :----------------: |
| 0 heads   | $\frac{4}{9}$             |
| 1 Head | $\frac{4}{9}$           |
| 2 heads |$\frac {1}{9}$|

and this is whjat I see in the editor
[image]

and this iw what I'm seeing on the question page
[image]

why is this?

Comment: You need newlines before the start of the table.

Comment: I see, thanks!!

Comment: A related bug report on Meta SE: [Markdown table preview does not detect missing blank line before table header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359192)